# Which language has best community for Data mining and Machine learning? Python, Java, c++ or any other?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I have the skills with C++, ruby,rails, and some other scripting languages. I want to start experimenting and learn concepts in Data mining and machine learning.

I want to be well equipped with the programming knowledge required for those concepts.

Which language has best support for DM and ML? puthon, Java, C++? Is there anything coming up in Javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that perhaps your question is a bit off target.  The languages themselves don't generally have the support: it's packages that interface with those languages, such as Apache Spark (interface to their ML package),  Intel's MKL (vector and matrix operations optimized for Xeon Phi), SciKit (Python interface), etc.

That said, I see the most active support for languages that drive at distributed processing.  In my ambit, Java/Spark is *currently* the front-runner, but one or two major releases can change the market considerably -- see the buzz on Tensor, for instance, or the staying power of BeautifulSoup.

For experimentation, start with your comfort zone.  There are plenty of good tools that interface well with Ruby and C++, as well.  As long as you're using this to learn the underlying concepts, I believe that you'll do best with a language you already know: that gives you one less area of frustration in your learning curve.

Anony-Mousse and Patricio have given you very good points with which I totally concur.  I'm working in Python and Scala, with Java and Spark just underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Use whatever you are most comfortable with.

At least if it has the basics around. JavaScript and PHP are not very good in this domain. They just don't scale well for numerical computations. Python, R, Java and Scala are most popular. Theres Matlab, but there is not much happening there anymore. There is Julia which has a similar syntax but which is much more alive and shows some promise, if it weren't for colum-major,1-indexed arrays and the matlab-like syntax. Some use Lua, others Mathematica...
There are many many factors that play a role.
For example, scripting languages like Python and R are really slow - but these two also interface very well to C libraries (and Fortran!) so if you nostly use them as a "driver" and the libraries do all the work then they can be very usable. Just make sure to not assume every module is fast...

Answer (score 0):

Python has a very strong support from the Data Science Community, you have very good packages like Pandas and Python has a very good integration with Spark